# what is the default expiration time of a cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, httpcookie

By default what will be the expiration time of a cookie added using C# code?

```
    HttpCookie myCookie= new HttpCookie("myCookie");
    myCookie.Value = txtCookie.Text;       
    // Add the cookie.
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The default [Expires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.expires%28VS.80%29.aspx) value for a cookie is not a static time, but it creates a Session cookie. This will stay active until the user closes their browser/clears their cookies. You can override this as required.

From the linked page:

> Setting the Expires property to MinValue makes this a session Cookie,
>   which is its default value

Comment: And the session cookie expires in 14 days by default (in Owin), see code here https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L24

Comment: It's not specific to C#, right? It's default behaviour in browsers as well? Like when you do `document.cookie = 'asd=123'` it persists till you close the browser too unless you specified an expiration time?

Answer (score -11):

20 minutes.
In IIS, click on your website, and go to Session State.  In the second box (Cookie Settings), you can change the time out(in minutes).

[image]

Comment: I downvoted this because this is for the Session cookie. This will not affect the timeout in the code shown in the original answer.

Comment: And this timeout is probably for the server-side *session* timeout. This has *nothing to do* with cookie expiry time.